# How do I use Promise.all() to defer returning an array that's being built inside the function?

Tags: javascript, arrays, promise, es6-promise

Below I'm attempting to assign a value, an array, to a local variable. I'm calling a function that returns an array to get that value. The problem is that the `Promises` in the 2nd function aren't resolved until after the array has been returned to the caller. I've tried using `Promise.all()` on `retArray` but it never works for me. When I `console.log()` out my `someobject` object the `arrOfTitles` field never prints out because the call to `SkywalkerTitles()` **returns an empty array**.

You can run the code [here](https://repl.it/L1e3/62).

So how do I get `someObject.arrOfTitles` to get the array of titles from `SkywalkerTitles()`?

```
function SkywalkerTitles(){
  let retArray = [];

  fetch('https://swapi.co/api/people/')
  .then(function(response){
    response.json()
    .then(function(result){
      return result.results[0];
    })
    .then(function(result){
       result.films.forEach(function(film){
        fetch(film)
        .then(function(response){
          response.json().then(function(result){
            console.log(result.title);
            retArray.push(result.title);
          });
        });
      })
      .catch(function(error){
        console.log(error)
      });
    });
  })
  .catch(function(error){
    console.log(error)
  });

}

function UseReturnedArray() {
  let someObject = { aThing: '', anotherThing: '', arrOfTitles: null };

  someObject.aThing = 'Thing One';
  someObject.anotherThing = 'Thing Two';
  someObject.arrOfTitles = SkywalkerTitles();

  console.log('Object With Returned Array:\n\n', JSON.stringify(someObject, null, 2));
}

UseReturnedArray();
```

Comment: If the promise correctly resolves to the array (which it doesn't seem to at the moment) and if you return the promise from the function (which you are also not doing): `SkywalkerTitles().then(result => someObject.arrOfTitles = result)`. You might want to have a look at [How do I return the response from an asynchronous call?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/14220321/218196)

Comment: `SkywalkerTitles` doesn't return anything ... so `someObject.arrOfTitles` will be `undefined` ... also, as `SkywalkerTitles` has an asynchronous component, the only thing `someObject.arrOfTitles` could ever be is a promise object

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As much as @Svenskunganka answer is complete and worthy, alternative if your environment doesn't yet support async/await AND you don't want to use a transpiler - seeing as you're already partially familiar with Promises, this code shouldn't look as foreign :p

Your main problem is that SkywalkerTitles doesn't actually return anything (you claim it returns an empty array, it actually has no return statement, therefore the returned value is `undefined`

I've also removed the `.catch` code, because where you had it would actually cause issues, in that your code handles rejections, yet further down the chain the code would expect that the data was actually valid! Only a single catch almost always ever needed

```
function SkywalkerTitles() {
    return fetch('https://swapi.co/api/people/').then(function (response) {
        return response.json();
    }).then(function (result) {
        return result.results[0];
    }).then(function (result) {
        return Promise.all(result.films.map(function (film) {
            return fetch(film).then(function (response) {
                return response.json();
            }).then(function (result) {
                return result.title;
            });
        }));
    });
}

function UseReturnedArray() {
    SkywalkerTitles().then(function (arrOfTitles) {
        var someObject = {
            aThing: '',
            anotherThing: '',
            arrOfTitles: arrOfTitles
        };
        console.log('Object With Returned Array:\n\n', JSON.stringify(someObject, null, 2));
    }).catch(function(reason) {
        console.log(reason);
    });
}
UseReturnedArray();
```

Note how the promise chain is flattened compared to yours, and use of `Array#map` instead of `Array#forEach + Array#push`

Comment: That old school nesting.. :x But 100% good example about how Promise works.

Comment: it's actually "babeljs" nesting :p

Comment: Thank you @JaromandaX .. not only does this work but your explanation helps me understand what is happening with the Promises. I left the return off of SkywalkerTitles() on purpose because I thought it was somehow connected to or reliant upon the Promise.all() I thought I needed so I left both Promise.all() and the return out of the sample code. Thanks again for the great answer.

Answer (score 1):

You should take advantage of async/await, which could really clean up your code quite a bit and make it more understandable:

```
async function SkywalkerTitles () {
  let character = await fetch('https://swapi.co/api/people/').then(res => res.json()).then(res => res.results[0])
  return await Promise.all(character.films.map(async (film) => {
    return await fetch(film).then(res => res.json()).then(res => res.title)
  }))
}

async function UseRetrunedArray () {
  try {
    let someObject = {
      aThing: '',
      anotherThing: '',
      arrOfTitles: await SkywalkerTitles()
    }

    console.log(someObject)
  } catch (e) {
    console.error(e)
  }
}

UseRetrunedArray()
```

See https://repl.it/Lc2f/2

If this looks alien to you, I suggest you read a bit into how `async`/`await` and `Promise` work together.

Comment: Thank you @Svenskunganka for the suggestion. I'll look into how async/await work with Promise. This syntax may take a bit for me to wrap my head around as I'm very new to working with Promises. Always appreciate an opportunity to learn though so thank you!